# Chrome DevTools - how to track network request when URL triggers Save dialog

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When the URL entered into the Chrome address bar results in the Save As dialog being popped (Content Type is not recognised), the network request never appears in the network tab in dev tools.

Is there a way I can track this to see the response headers from within Chrome, ie. without resorting to external tools like tcpdump or fiddler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to access the request/response data in a more raw form using the network internals interface provided in Chrome. Navigate to `chrome://net-internals/` (can't make it a link)

1. Click on the 'Events' links to see the recent requests and active sockets. I recommend using the filter at the top to remove some of the noise.
2. Select the relevant entry corresponding to the source type `URL_REQUEST`.
3. On the right hand side, you will see a whole load of data, but the request headers will appear under the `HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST_HEADERS` section, and the response headers will appear under the `HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_RESPONSE_HEADERS` section.

The following is  an example from a simple Node server I set up to return a response with the `'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'}` header. This forces the browser to download.

[image: Network internals]